# What is a glom?. How it is different from mapPartitions?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I've come across the `glom()` method on RDD. As per the documentation

> Return an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each partition into an array

Does `glom` shuffle the data across the partitions or does it only return the partition data as an array? In the latter case, I believe that the same can be achieved using `mapPartitions`.

I would also like to know if there are any use cases that benefit from `glom`.

Comment: @zero323 explained in a nice way ... wanted to add imp. tip i.e.  `glom` is useful when you want to implement RDD operations using matrix libraries that are optimized to operate on arrays

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does `glom` shuffle the data across partitions

No, it doesn't

> If this is the second case I believe that the same can be achieved using mapPartitions

It can:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(_.toArray))
```

but the same thing applies to any non shuffling transformation like `map`, `flatMap` or `filter`.

> if there are any use cases which benefit from glob.

Any situation where you need to access partition data in a form that is traversable more than once.

Comment: Can't we traverse more than once from the output of mapPartitions or map or filter?

Comment: Not exactly what I mean. Lets say you have a functions `(vs: T) => for { x <- vs; y <- vs } yield (x, y)` and you want to apply it to the complete partitions. You can simply `rdd.glom.map(f)` instead of converting Iterator inside mapPartitions. But in general it is not a crucial function.

Answer (score 9):

`glom()` transforms each partition into a tuple (immutabe list) of elements. It creates an `RDD` of tuples. One tuple per partition.

Answer (score 0):

"... Glom()
In general, spark does not allow the worker to refer to specific elements of the RDD.
Keeps the language clean, but can be a major limitation.
**glom()** transforms each partition into a tuple (immutabe list) of elements.
Creates an RDD of tules. One tuple per partition.
workers can refer to elements of the partition by index. 
but you cannot assign values to the elements, the RDD is still immutable.
Now we can understand the command used above to count the number of elements in each partition.
We use `glom()` to make each partition into a tuple.
We use `len` on each partition to get the length of the tuple - size of the partition.
* We `collect` the results to print them out.

Answer (score 0):

The glom() function returns an RDD that is created by grouping all elements within each partition into a list(called tuple as it is an immutable list).
You can sort it like this -
`rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) sorted(rdd.glom().collect()) [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`