# How to use Spark's repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to build a minimal working example of `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` in order to understand the function. I have got so far (not working, the distinct throws the values around so that they get out of order)

```
def partval(partID:Int, iter: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[Tuple2[Int, Int]] = {
  iter.map( x => (partID, x)).toList.iterator
}

val part20to3_chaos = sc.parallelize(1 to 20, 3).distinct
val part20to2_sorted = part20to3_chaos.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(2)
part20to2_sorted.mapPartitionsWithIndex(partval).collect
```

but get the error

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:22: error: value repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
             val part20to2_sorted = part20to3_chaos.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(2)
```

I tried using the [scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html), but wasn't able to find which class provides `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`. (Btw: This scaladoc is not impressive: Why is `MapPartitionsRDD` missing? How can I search for a method?)

Realising I need a partitioner object, next I tried to

```
val rangePartitioner = new org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner(2, part20to3_chaos)
val part20to2_sorted = part20to3_chaos.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(rangePartitioner)
part20to2_sorted.mapPartitionsWithIndex(partval).collect
```

but got

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ <: Product2[?,?]]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
         val rPartitioner = new org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner(2, part20to3_chaos)
```

How do I get this to compile? Could I get a working example, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `part20to3_chaos` is an `RDD[Int]`, while [`OrderedRDDFunctions.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions) is a method which operates on an `RDD[(K, V)]`, where `K` is the key and `V` is the value.

`repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` will first *repartition* the data based on the provided partitioner, and then *sort by the key*:

```
/**
 * Repartition the RDD according to the given partitioner and, 
 * within each resulting partition, sort records by their keys.
 *
 * This is more efficient than calling `repartition` and then sorting within each partition
 * because it can push the sorting down into the shuffle machinery.
 */
def repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, V)] = 
  self.withScope {
    new ShuffledRDD[K, V, V](self, partitioner).setKeyOrdering(ordering)
}
```

So it looks like it's not exactly what you're looking for.

If you want a plain old sort, you can use `sortBy`, as it doesn't require a key:

```
scala> val toTwenty = sc.parallelize(1 to 20, 3).distinct
toTwenty: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[31] at distinct at <console>:33

scala> val sorted = toTwenty.sortBy(identity, true, 3).collect
sorted: Array[Int] = 
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Where you pass `sortBy` the order (ascending or descending), and the number of partitions you want to create.

Comment: `mapPartitionsWithIndex` was supposed to be only used for display-purposes, not for the actual thing. I don't get it: I thought `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` would repartition my RDD like `repartition` and then sort the RDD's elements within each partition, for each partition. Why would it need `(K,V)`? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, I think you are missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @Make42 See my edit. Where am I missing parenthesis?

Comment: `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new RangePartitioner[Int, Int](2, secondPart)` <- closing parenthesis

Comment: @Make42 Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to explain repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions thru pyspark.

Suppose you have a dataset in pair form

```
pairs  = sc.parallelize([["a",1], ["b",2], ["c",3], ["d",3]])

pairs.collect() 
# Output [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 3]]
pairs.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(2).glom().collect() 
# Output [[('a', 1), ('c', 3)], [('b', 2), ('d', 3)]]
```

Thru repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions() we asked the data to be reshuffled in 2 partitions and that's exactly what we get. 'a' and 'c' as one 'b' and 'd' as another one. The keys are sorted.

We can also repartition-n-sort based on certain condition, as

```
pairs.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(2, 
                                         partitionFunc=lambda x: x == 'a').glom().collect()
# Output [[('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 3)], [('a', 1)]]
```

As expected we have two partitions one with 3 key-pairs sorted and one with ('a',1).  To know more about glom refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738508/what-is-a-glom-how-it-is-different-from-mappartitions)